# "to carry away" - concrete meaning

Tags: meaning

The [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/carry-away) says that "to carry away" can mean:

1. to remove forcefully
2. (usually passive) to cause (a person) to lose self-control
3. (usually passive) to delight or enrapture

Is its concrete meaning (to carry something away from here, eg furniture, garbage, luggage) also possible/usual?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is the basic meaning from which the idiomatic "remove forcibly" is derived. But often a different verb can be used "Take the furniture away", for example.

Comment: It seems to be that not only a different verb *can* be used, but it *is* often used. I have always seen "to take away" used instead of "to carry away" (same for "to take out"  / "to carry out").